# How can I get Lewis-like structures + illustrate electron transfer

Tags: arrows, mhchem, chemstyle, chemfig

I know about the existence of packages that allow Lewis structures but that is not the question.  The question is how to illustrate radical reactions as depicted below.  The solution would ideally be typeset as inline text, not a picture.  The solution should not involve TikZ.

Edit: A solution which uses a pre-defined macro is preferred.  "Picture-based" solutions like TikZ are just too involved because everything has to be defined from scratch.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you can draw the curly arrows without either using specials (either PostScript or PDF) or creating a suitable font.  The specials route suggests a picture, which you've ruled out, so this is a bit of a poser.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: The reason for my ruling out of "picture-based" approaches was because I wanted to avoid heavy-handed solutions like TikZ, which generate things from scratch and really take clutter in your latex document to a whole new level.  I was hopeful an existing chemistry package would allow radical reactions to be depicted.  I'd be surprised if this wasn't possible...?  What do you think?  Ultimately, if no package does this to your knowledge, feel free to suggest a solution that isn't too elaborate, so a novice like me can follow.

Comment: I'm realy not sure how you can do that without  something special. The suitable font  is perhaps a solution but I do not believe. Inline solutiob with Tikz is not a problem but I think in this case you need to have a good baseline (see your picture)  Now if you want on another domain, see example of what you can do without heavy-handed solutions, looks at http://elishapeterson.wikidot.com/tikz:diagrams Tikz can avoid heavy-handed solutions.

Comment: It seems to me that you wouldn't mind using TikZ as such, but would like an already finished package utilizing it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Thanks for following. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pershaps, the chemfig package may help you though it relies on tikz? Here is the first reaction:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
text before
\schemestart
    \setlewis{4pt}{}{red}\Lewis{0:,\chemfig{@{a}\textcolor{red}{A}}}\hskip4pt\chemfig{@{b}\textcolor{black!40!green}{B}}%
    \arrow
    \Lewis{0.,A}%
    \+\Lewis{4.,B}%
    \chemmove{\draw[red,-stealth]([xshift=9pt]a.90)..controls+(90:10pt) and +(90:10pt)..([yshift=2pt]a.90);
    \draw[black!40!green,-stealth]([xshift=9pt]a.-90)..controls+(-90:10pt) and +(-90:10pt)..([yshift=-2pt]b.-90);}%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it is impossible to have electrons colored (which I thought it was possible) because of a bug in chemfig I discovered a few minutes ago!

EDIT: here is a quick fix for chemfig about the `\lewis` command:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\makeatletter
\def\CF@lewis@ii#1,#2\@nil#3{%
        \setbox\CF@lewis@box\hbox{\printatom{#2}}%
        \node(CF@lewis@anchor){};
        \def\CF@lewis@remainpos{#1}%
        \let\CF@lewis@previouspos\@empty
        \loop
            \unless\ifx\CF@lewis@remainpos\@empty
                \edef\CF@lewis@currentpos{\expandafter\@car\CF@lewis@remainpos\@nil}%
                \edef\CF@lewis@remainpos{\expandafter\@gobble\CF@lewis@remainpos}%
                \pgfmathparse{\wd\CF@lewis@box/2+\ifcase\CF@lewis@currentpos\space1\or1\or0\or-1\or-1\or-1\or0\or1\fi*(\wd\CF@lewis@box/2+\CF@lewis@offset)}%
                \let\CF@lewis@x\pgfmathresult
                \pgfmathparse{\ht\CF@lewis@box/2+\ifcase\CF@lewis@currentpos\space0\or1\or1\or1\or0\or-1\or-1\or-1\fi*(\ht\CF@lewis@box/2\ifnum\CF@lewis@currentpos>4 +\dp\CF@lewis@box\fi+\CF@lewis@offset)}%
                \let\CF@lewis@y\pgfmathresult
                \edef\CF@lewis@xoffset{\ifcase\CF@lewis@currentpos\space
                    0\or0.70711\or1\or0.70711\or0\or-0.70711\or-1\or-0.70711\fi}%
                \edef\CF@lewis@yoffset{\ifcase\CF@lewis@currentpos\space
                    -1\or-0.70711\or0\or0.70711\or1\or0.70711\or0\or-0.70711\fi}%
                \pgfmathparse{veclen(\CF@lewis@xoffset,\CF@lewis@yoffset)}\let\CF@len@normvec\pgfmathresult
                \edef\CF@lewis@diagmul{\ifcase\CF@lewis@currentpos\space1\or0\or1\or0\or1\or0\or1\or0\fi}% annule l'offset pour les diagonales
                \if.\expandafter\@car\CF@lewis@remainpos\relax\@nil
                    \edef\CF@lewis@remainpos{\expandafter\@gobble\CF@lewis@remainpos}%
                    \CF@expand@afterfirst{\draw[fill,black,}{\CF@lewis@style,#3]}%
                        (\CF@lewis@x pt-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.1ex,
                        \CF@lewis@y pt+\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.1ex)circle(0.15ex);%
                \else
                    \if|\expandafter\@car\CF@lewis@remainpos\relax\@nil
                        \edef\CF@lewis@remainpos{\expandafter\@gobble\CF@lewis@remainpos}%
                        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@lewis@style,#3]%
                            (\CF@lewis@x-\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@xoffset/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y-\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@yoffset/2 pt)--
                            ([xshift=-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@widthdouble,yshift=\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@widthdouble]\CF@lewis@x-\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@length/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@length/2 pt)--
                            ([xshift=-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@widthdouble,yshift=\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@widthdouble]\CF@lewis@x+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@xoffset/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@yoffset/2 pt)--
                            (\CF@lewis@x+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@xoffset/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@yoffset/2 pt)--cycle;%
                    \else
                        \if:\expandafter\@car\CF@lewis@remainpos\relax\@nil
                            \edef\CF@lewis@remainpos{\expandafter\@gobble\CF@lewis@remainpos}%
                            \CF@expand@afterfirst{\draw[fill,black,}{\CF@lewis@style,#3]}%
                                (\CF@lewis@x pt-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.2ex-.2em*\CF@lewis@xoffset/\CF@len@normvec,\CF@lewis@y pt+\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.2ex-.2em*\CF@lewis@yoffset/\CF@len@normvec)circle(0.15ex)%
                                (\CF@lewis@x pt-\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.2ex+.2em*\CF@lewis@xoffset/\CF@len@normvec,\CF@lewis@y pt+\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@diagmul*0.2ex+.2em*\CF@lewis@yoffset/\CF@len@normvec)circle(0.15ex);%
                        \else
                            \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@lewis@style,#3]%
                                (\CF@lewis@x-\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@xoffset/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y-\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@yoffset/2 pt)--%
                                (\CF@lewis@x+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@xoffset/2 pt,\CF@lewis@y+\CF@lewis@length*\CF@lewis@yoffset/2 pt);%
                        \fi
                    \fi
            \fi
        \repeat
        \node[anchor=base west]at(CF@lewis@anchor){\box\CF@lewis@box};%
    \endtikzpicture
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
text before
\schemestart
    \rlap{\setlewis{4pt}{}{red,yshift=1.5pt}\Lewis{0.,\chemfig{@{a}\textcolor{red}{A}}}}%
    \setlewis{4pt}{}{black!40!green,yshift=-1.5pt}\Lewis{0.,\chemfig{@{a}\phantom{A}}}%
    \hskip4pt\chemfig{@{b}\textcolor{black!40!green}{B}}%
    \arrow
    \setlewis{}{}{red}\Lewis{0.,\textcolor{red}{A}}%
    \setlewis{}{}{black!40!green}\+\Lewis{4.,\textcolor{black!40!green}{B}}%
    \chemmove{\draw[red,-stealth]([xshift=8.5pt]a.90)..controls+(90:10pt) and +(90:10pt)..([yshift=2pt]a.90);
    \draw[black!40!green,-stealth]([xshift=8.5pt]a.-90)..controls+(-90:10pt) and +(-90:10pt)..([yshift=-2pt]b.-90);}%
\schemestop
\vspace{1cm}

text before
\schemestart
    \setlewis{4pt}{}{blue}\Lewis{0:,\chemfig{\textcolor{red}{A}}}\hskip4pt\chemfig{@{bb}\textcolor{blue}{B}}%
    \arrow
    \chemfig[red]{A^+}\+\chemfig[blue]{\setlewis{}{}{blue}\Lewis{4:,B^{-}}}%
    \chemmove{\draw[blue,-stealth]([xshift=-8.5pt]bb.90)..controls+(90:10pt) and +(90:10pt)..([yshift=2pt]bb.90);}%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: :) A bug?  Could you please report it to the package author/maintainer, as I wouldn't know what to say?  Maybe they'll be willing to fix it.  I got the impression the maintainer of chemfig was reasonably active.

Comment: Did it compile for you?  I got an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \schemestart`

Comment: @ptrcao I am the author and maintainer of chemfig. If you cannot compile the code, plase, update your latex distribution to works with the latest version 1.0 of chemfig, uploaded in then CTAN the 2011/06/15.

Comment: My TL2010 manager says there is no update available?  Local ver=0.4b, remote ver=0.4b.  `tlmgr: no updates available`

Comment: @ptrcao Of crourse. Since TL2010 is frozen, there is no update available with it. Download the chemfig.tex file in the CTAN and copy it into the same directory as the source of your document.

Comment: On tl2011, we have only  chemfig v0.4b  April 24, 2011. I think it's preferable to get the package from ctan.

Comment: It's ok with the latest version and don't forget to compile twice !

Comment: Wait, the way I manually install packages is to put the .sty file into the default package directory C:\texlive\2010\texmf\tex\latex - but where are all the .sty files - they used to be there - they don't appear to be there anymore...?  (Also, I don't want to be putting the .sty file into the directory with the source of my document do I, cause I want it to be available no matter where the source of the document is, right...?)

Comment: @unbonpetit: The output looks great; one little minor tweaking request though before we call it case closed.  Do you know how to make the arrow heads half harpoons, like in the original?

Comment: @ptrcao Just add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in the preamble after `\usepackage{chemfig}` and replace the arrow `stealth` by `left to` or `right to`.